# Searching xml attribute having similar values

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, c#-2.0

I have an xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<content>
  <field title="Year">
    <description>Numeric data</description>
    <comment>1234</comment>
  </field>
  <field title="mail">
    <description>Numeric data</description>
    <comment>ABCD</comment>
  </field>
<field title="Years">
    <description>AlphNumeric Data</description>
    <comment>ABCD1234</comment>
  </field>
</content>
```

using below code Im extracting node values of `<description>` and `<Comment>` that comes under attribute Title with Value='year'

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
XmlNodeList xnList = xml.SelectNodes("/contentr/field[@title='"+ searchdata +"']");
```

if searchdata = 'year' then
this will extract only node values of attribute with value 'year'.But i need to extract all  data with attribute value contains  'year' as well as 'years'

is there anyway to achieve this  ?  iam working on c# ,ver 2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `contains()` function:

```
xml.SelectNodes("/content/field[contains(@title,'" + searchdata + "')]")
```